# SAP Fiori client using device sound

Tags: cordova, audio, client, sap-fiori

Can you access (different if possible) device sounds when working with SAP Fiori client (and Cordova, Kapsel,...) I'd like to make different sound feedbacks on different scenarios, differing in length and pitch of the sound/tone.

I found that you can access the mic via kapsel-plugin-voicerecording but I couldn't find anything on output.

Is there any other plugin, or any way I could access these functions on the device?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. It looks like you are looking for an *off-site resource*?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to access sound-output from an external device running the sap fiori client. If by an off-site resource or sap fiori way if there is one.

Comment: Anyone? I really need an answer to this question!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following plugins are capable of playing sounds. Perhaps one of them might work for you.

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/